# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to change the root password for PhPMyAdmin which has 10.1.13-MariaDB
 by typing the following in the SQL tab and hitting on the `Go` button:

```
ALTER USER
  'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'
```

I get this error:

```
Error
SQL query:


ALTER USER
  'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER
>         'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'' at line 1

I followed [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) on MySQL website:

> Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a
>   single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to
>   use.
>
> MySQL 5.7.6 and later:
>
> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'`
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:
>
> `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?

Comment: I just installed XAMPP from Apache Friend and it installed all other things including PhPMyAdmin and MySQL on Windows 7

Comment: OK - What version of the database are you using?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 10.1.13-MariaDB

Comment: It's all here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/set-password/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for MariaDB:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpass')
```

After you change the password you will see the following in PhPMyAdmin:
[image] which says : `mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings.`

You should open the `config.inc.php` file and change the following lines:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

To:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'newpass';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

This file by default is in `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin` directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and documenting.

Comment: you are welcome @Drew! Thought to save future developer's time :)